# Optimizing an implementation of the RKF method

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods

This is an algorithm regarding the [RKF method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method):

```
import numpy as np

class rkf():

    def __init__(self,f, a, b, x0, atol, rtol, hmax, hmin):
        self.f=f
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.x0=x0
        self.atol=atol
        self.rtol=rtol
        self.hmax=hmax
        self.hmin=hmin

    def solve(self):

        a2  =   2.500000000000000e-01  #  1/4
        a3  =   3.750000000000000e-01  #  3/8
        a4  =   9.230769230769231e-01  #  12/13
        a5  =   1.000000000000000e+00  #  1
        a6  =   5.000000000000000e-01  #  1/2

        b21 =   2.500000000000000e-01  #  1/4
        b31 =   9.375000000000000e-02  #  3/32
        b32 =   2.812500000000000e-01  #  9/32
        b41 =   8.793809740555303e-01  #  1932/2197
        b42 =  -3.277196176604461e+00  # -7200/2197
        b43 =   3.320892125625853e+00  #  7296/2197
        b51 =   2.032407407407407e+00  #  439/216
        b52 =  -8.000000000000000e+00  # -8
        b53 =   7.173489278752436e+00  #  3680/513
        b54 =  -2.058966861598441e-01  # -845/4104
        b61 =  -2.962962962962963e-01  # -8/27
        b62 =   2.000000000000000e+00  #  2
        b63 =  -1.381676413255361e+00  # -3544/2565
        b64 =   4.529727095516569e-01  #  1859/4104
        b65 =  -2.750000000000000e-01  # -11/40

        r1  =   2.777777777777778e-03  #  1/360
        r3  =  -2.994152046783626e-02  # -128/4275
        r4  =  -2.919989367357789e-02  # -2197/75240
        r5  =   2.000000000000000e-02  #  1/50
        r6  =   3.636363636363636e-02  #  2/55

        c1  =   1.157407407407407e-01  #  25/216
        c3  =   5.489278752436647e-01  #  1408/2565
        c4  =   5.353313840155945e-01  #  2197/4104
        c5  =  -2.000000000000000e-01  # -1/5
        
        
        t = self.a
        x = np.array(self.x0)
        h = self.hmax

        T = np.array( [t] )
        X = np.array( [x] )
        
        while t < self.b:

            if t + h > self.b:
                h = self.b - t

            k1 = h * self.f(t, x)
            k2 = h * self.f(t + a2 * h, x + b21 * k1 )
            k3 = h * self.f(t + a3 * h, x + b31 * k1 + b32 * k2)
            k4 = h * self.f(t + a4 * h, x + b41 * k1 + b42 * k2 + b43 * k3)
            k5 = h * self.f(t + a5 * h, x + b51 * k1 + b52 * k2 + b53 * k3 + b54 * k4)
            k6 = h * self.f(t + a6 * h, x + b61 * k1 + b62 * k2 + b63 * k3 + b64 * k4 + b65 * k5)

            r = abs( r1 * k1 + r3 * k3 + r4 * k4 + r5 * k5 + r6 * k6 ) / h
            r = r / (self.atol+self.rtol*(abs(x)+abs(k1)))
            if len( np.shape( r ) ) > 0:
                r = max( r )
            if r <= 1:
                t = t + h
                x = x + c1 * k1 + c3 * k3 + c4 * k4 + c5 * k5
                T = np.append( T, t )
                X = np.append( X, [x], 0 )
            h = h * min( max( 0.94 * ( 1 / r )**0.25, 0.1 ), 4.0 )
            if h > self.hmax:
                h = self.hmax
            elif h < self.hmin or t==t-h:
                raise RuntimeError("Error: Could not converge to the required tolerance.")
                break

        return (T,X)
```

Which works just fine, but I was wondering if is it possible to make this even faster and more efficient?

Comment: This looks like an excerpt of a class method. Please show all of your code.

Comment: @Reinderien As you requested, I just did.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to include [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) to increase the readability of and document your program. Also take a look at Python [naming conventions](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#naming-conventions) for classes (CamelCase) and variables (lowercase only). Lastly, you don't need the empty brackets in `class rkf():` --> `class RKF:`.

Comment: @riskypenguin That feedback belongs in an answer

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you implemented the algorithm correctly. After a quick look at the Wikipedia article, there seems to be a few notable differences between your implementation and the one described on Wikipedia, but since I don't know much about your code or what it's supposed to accomplish, I can't tell if those are intended or not.

Comment: @cliesnes The main difference between my implementation and the one in Wikipedia, is that Wikipedia only defines "Tolerance" and hence, cannot efficiently tackle a system of ODEs (specially when the ODEs have different order of magnitudes) . But I used the absolute Tolerance and relative tolerance to tackle that problem. Besides that, the main algorithm is the same as Wiki's.

Comment: @riskypenguin Thanks for your feedback, I'll try my best to name everything better next time :)) but I was hoping that you would have any thoughts on how to increase the efficiency of this code... somehow(?) Since I think the main algorithm is straightforward (?)

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you're already using Numpy and you find that you are motivated to do loop unrolling in an attempt to make things fast, it's time to switch to C and use lower-level vectorized libraries
- Your class does not deserve to be a class, and should just be a function
- You should add type hints
- There is really no reason to pre-compute your fractions as you have. This makes so marginal a speed difference, at a cost of so worse a legibility and maintainability, that it isn't worth it compared to other efforts like switching language
- `k`, `A`, `R` and `C` are obviously vectors, and `B` is obviously a triangular matrix. Best to actually represent them as such.
- Since `T` and `X` are being frequently reallocated, there's no advantage to using numpy - just use Python lists
- Your calculation for `k` is actually a series of dot-products, and so it's best to just call into `np.dot`
- You're not using in-place operators where you should, i.e. `t = t + h` should just be `t += h`
- This condition:

  ```
        if t + h > self.b:
            h = self.b - t
  ```

is more legible as

```
        if h > b - t:
            h = b - t
```

When doing all of the above, I experience a marginal slowdown of 4.2 us in exchange for greater legibility and maintainability, and centralized constants.

### Alternate implementation

```
from functools import partial
from timeit import timeit
from typing import Callable, Tuple, Sequence

import numpy as np


class rkf_old():

    def __init__(self, f, a, b, x0, atol, rtol, hmax, hmin):
        self.f = f
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.x0 = x0
        self.atol = atol
        self.rtol = rtol
        self.hmax = hmax
        self.hmin = hmin

    def solve(self):

        a2 = 2.500000000000000e-01  # 1/4
        a3 = 3.750000000000000e-01  # 3/8
        a4 = 9.230769230769231e-01  # 12/13
        a5 = 1.000000000000000e+00  # 1
        a6 = 5.000000000000000e-01  # 1/2

        b21 = 2.500000000000000e-01  # 1/4
        b31 = 9.375000000000000e-02  # 3/32
        b32 = 2.812500000000000e-01  # 9/32
        b41 = 8.793809740555303e-01  # 1932/2197
        b42 = -3.277196176604461e+00  # -7200/2197
        b43 = 3.320892125625853e+00  # 7296/2197
        b51 = 2.032407407407407e+00  # 439/216
        b52 = -8.000000000000000e+00  # -8
        b53 = 7.173489278752436e+00  # 3680/513
        b54 = -2.058966861598441e-01  # -845/4104
        b61 = -2.962962962962963e-01  # -8/27
        b62 = 2.000000000000000e+00  # 2
        b63 = -1.381676413255361e+00  # -3544/2565
        b64 = 4.529727095516569e-01  # 1859/4104
        b65 = -2.750000000000000e-01  # -11/40

        r1 = 2.777777777777778e-03  # 1/360
        r3 = -2.994152046783626e-02  # -128/4275
        r4 = -2.919989367357789e-02  # -2197/75240
        r5 = 2.000000000000000e-02  # 1/50
        r6 = 3.636363636363636e-02  # 2/55

        c1 = 1.157407407407407e-01  # 25/216
        c3 = 5.489278752436647e-01  # 1408/2565
        c4 = 5.353313840155945e-01  # 2197/4104
        c5 = -2.000000000000000e-01  # -1/5

        t = self.a
        x = np.array(self.x0)
        h = self.hmax

        T = np.array([t])
        X = np.array([x])

        while t < self.b:

            if t + h > self.b:
                h = self.b - t

            k1 = h * self.f(t, x)
            k2 = h * self.f(t + a2 * h, x + b21 * k1)
            k3 = h * self.f(t + a3 * h, x + b31 * k1 + b32 * k2)
            k4 = h * self.f(t + a4 * h, x + b41 * k1 + b42 * k2 + b43 * k3)
            k5 = h * self.f(t + a5 * h, x + b51 * k1 + b52 * k2 + b53 * k3 + b54 * k4)
            k6 = h * self.f(t + a6 * h, x + b61 * k1 + b62 * k2 + b63 * k3 + b64 * k4 + b65 * k5)

            r = abs(r1 * k1 + r3 * k3 + r4 * k4 + r5 * k5 + r6 * k6) / h
            r = r / (self.atol + self.rtol * (abs(x) + abs(k1)))
            if len(np.shape(r)) > 0:
                r = max(r)
            if r <= 1:
                t = t + h
                x = x + c1 * k1 + c3 * k3 + c4 * k4 + c5 * k5
                T = np.append(T, t)
                X = np.append(X, [x], 0)
            h = h * min(max(0.94 * (1 / r) ** 0.25, 0.1), 4.0)
            if h > self.hmax:
                h = self.hmax
            elif h < self.hmin or t == t - h:
                raise RuntimeError("Error: Could not converge to the required tolerance.")
                break

        return (T, X)


def rkf(
    f: Callable[[float, float], float],
    a: float, b: float, x0: float,
    atol: float, rtol: float,
    hmax: float, hmin: float,
) -> Tuple[
    Sequence[float], Sequence[float],
]:
    A = np.array((0, 1/4, 3/8, 12/13, 1, 1/2))
    B = np.array((
        (        0,          0,          0,         0,      0, 0),
        (      1/4,          0,          0,         0,      0, 0),
        (     3/32,       9/32,          0,         0,      0, 0),
        (1932/2197, -7200/2197,  7296/2197,         0,      0, 0),
        (  439/216,         -8,   3680/513, -845/4104,      0, 0),
        (    -8/27,          2, -3544/2565, 1859/4104, -11/40, 0),
    ))
    R = np.array((1/360, 0, -128/4275, -2197/75240, 1/50, 2/55))
    C = np.array((25/216, 0, 1408/2565, 2197/4104, -1/5))

    k = np.empty((6,))
    t = a
    x = x0
    h = hmax

    T = [t]
    X = [x0]

    while t < b:
        if h > b - t:
            h = b - t

        Ta = A*h + t

        for i, ta in enumerate(Ta):
            k[i] = h * f(ta, x + np.dot(
                B[i, :i],
                k[:i],
            ))

        r = np.abs(np.dot(R, k)) / h
        r /= atol + rtol * (np.abs(x) + np.abs(k[0]))
        if len(np.shape(r)) > 0:
            r = max(r)
        if r <= 1:
            t += h
            x += np.dot(C, k[:5])
            T.append(t)
            X.append(x)
        h *= min(max(0.94 * (1 / r) ** 0.25, 0.1), 4.0)
        if h > hmax:
            h = hmax
        elif h < hmin or t == t - h:
            raise ValueError("Error: Could not converge to the required tolerance.")

    return T, X


def test_fun(t: float, k: float) -> float:
    return 3*t - 2*k + 1/(t**2 + k**2)


def main():
    args = dict(f=test_fun, a=-3, b=11, x0=-1, atol=1e-3, rtol=-3, hmax=100, hmin=-100)

    old = rkf_old(**args).solve
    new = partial(rkf, **args)

    for method in (old, new):
        t, x = method()
        print(t)
        print(x)

        N = 20_000
        print(f'{timeit(method, number=N)/N*1e6:.1f} us')



main()
```

This outputs

```
[-3 11]
[-1.00000000e+00 -6.00218231e+05]
53.9 us

[-3, 11]
[-1, -600218.2310934969]
58.1 us
```

Comment: I did suspect those coefficients to be vectors and matrix, but I was stumbling on how to implement it, and your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

All these lines are really weird:

```
a4  =   9.230769230769231e-01  #  12/13
```

Unless you have a good reason (which I'd then state in the code as a comment) to do that, just write `a4 = 12/13` instead.

Gonna be the same anyway:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('a4 = 12/13')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0.9230769230769231)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a4)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('a4 = 9.230769230769231e-01')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0.9230769230769231)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a4)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

This line for example is not right:

```
b51 =   2.032407407407407e+00  #  439/216
```

The values differ slightly, your value being less accurate:

```
>>> 2.032407407407407e+00
2.032407407407407
>>> 439/216
2.0324074074074074
```

Comment: I'm not sure your if suggestion would make the code more efficient. Do you have any thoughts on the main algorithm? (By main algorithm, I mean what happens in the while loop)

Comment: Since I showed that it's gonna be the same (except for the minor value differences), you should be sure that it does *not* make it more efficient :-). No other thoughts, looks too complicated for me right now and I'm a newb at numpy.

Answer (score 2):

A significant improvement is to use lists and Python's built in append and convert the final list to array, instead of using np.append. I've run a test to demonstrate the performance enhancement:

```
def lorenz(t,u):
    s=10
    r=24
    b=8/3
    x,y,z=u
    vx=s*y-s*x
    vy=r*x-x*z-y
    vz=x*y-b*z
    return np.array([vx,vy,vz])

x0=[2,2,2]

t, u  = rkf( f=lorenz, a=0, b=1e+3, x0=x0, atol=1e-8, rtol=1e-6 , hmax=1e-1, hmin=1e-40,show_info=True).solve()
```

Now, when using numpy arrays and np.append I get:

```
Execution time: 56.7198397 seconds
Number of data points: 120732
```

Using list and Python's append:

```
Execution time: 8.3110496 seconds
Number of data points: 120732
```

Which is a huge difference on the performance. Also another slight improvement is to use sqrt(sqrt()) instead of **0.25 :

```
h = h * min( max( 0.94 * sqrt(sqrt( 1 / r )), 0.1 ), 4.0 )
```

Feel free to add your thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: I suspect that the performance boost of using the built-in isn't due to stock Python being faster, but rather misuse of numpy. Rather than appends, having a fixed-size array and doing slice assignments to it should help.